# Visual Basic: Jump to a sub procedure without running the code after it

Tags: vba

In the code below, I would like to have it so when the sub `code()` is run, and the `condition` is equal to `false`, then it will end the sub `test()`, not display the message `"hello"` and stop all scripts. Could someone please tell me how to do so?

```
Private Sub test()
    Call code
    MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub

Private Sub code()
    If Condition = False Then
    End If
    MsgBox ("Hello World")
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `Return` after the `Call condition()`!?

Comment: I have re-phrased the question. Sorry for the inconvenience @luk2302

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use `Return` or `Exit Sub` in the following way:

```
If condition = false Then
  Call condition()
  Return
End If
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha.aspx tells you

> When a Sub procedure returns to the calling code, execution continues with the statement after the statement that called it.
>   The following example shows a return from a Sub procedure.
>
> ```
> Sub mySub(ByVal q As String)
>   Return
> End Sub
> ```
>
> The `Exit Sub` and `Return` statements cause an immediate exit from a Sub procedure. Any number of Exit Sub and Return statements can appear anywhere in the procedure, and you can mix Exit Sub and Return statements.

To break out of the calling sub as well, the inner sub has to return a value indicating to the calling sub that it should not print, there is no built-in way.

Comment: `Exit Sub` and `Return` will not prevent the message "hello", as requested.

Comment: @omegastripes It will do for the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Put an

```
Exit Sub
```

After the Call condition()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use if then else

```
Private Sub code()
 If condition = false Then
  Call condition()
 else
  MsgBox("Hello World")
 End If
End Sub

Private Sub condition()
  MsgBox("Failure")
End Sub
```

[more on this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `End` keyword:

```
Const Condition = False

Private Sub test()
    Call code
    MsgBox ("Hello")
End Sub

Private Sub code()
    If Condition = False Then
        End
    End If
    MsgBox ("Hello World")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had set `On Error` Do nothing. So, it was an error and VBA compiler wasn't showing any error.

```
On Error GoTo errorRoutine

'Your Code Goes Here...

Exit Sub
errorRoutine:
```

I simply found the error and it starts working.